# R package installation with gfortran warnings in OSX

Tags: r, macos, compilation, gfortran

I have now been searching the web and tried different methods to get a R library (ctsmr) installed from the source, but without luck. I know it works on Linux and Windows, but have not succeeded on my Mac (OSX v10.12.6) with R v3.3.3.

When I try to install it like this:

```
install.packages("ctsmr", repo="http://ctsm.info/repo/dev", type="source")
```

I get the some warnings during the installation process, but the installation finishes.

```
* installing *source* package ‘ctsmr’ ...
** libs
gfortran-4.8 -fopenmp -fPIC -Wall -g -O2  -c  fdf.f90 -o fdf.o
gfortran-4.8: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘16.7.0
fdf.f90:19.30:

      INTEGER          I,ISTOP
                              1
Warning: Unused variable 'istop' declared at (1)
gfortran-4.8   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c matutil.f -o matutil.o
gfortran-4.8: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘16.7.0
gfortran-4.8   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c opkda1.f -o opkda1.o
...
```

When I run an example in RStudio (the one that is called "Building 1" on the packages webpage, http://ctsm.info) I get an error message for one of the function from the package. (This error message actually does not show up at the moment, as RStudio just crash when I run the line):

```
fit <- model$estimate(data=X)

Error in dyn.load(x = m$libfile) : 
  unable to load shared object '/var/folders/7g/81dqdb9s4qq2r79ncggcv2l40000gn/T//RtmpNoNnQl/model5a613c359b3f.so':
  dlopen(/var/folders/7g/81dqdb9s4qq2r79ncggcv2l40000gn/T//RtmpNoNnQl/model5a613c359b3f.so, 6): Symbol not found: _GOMP_parallel_end
  Referenced from: /var/folders/7g/81dqdb9s4qq2r79ncggcv2l40000gn/T//RtmpNoNnQl/model5a613c359b3f.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

It looks a little different if I run the same script in the R application:

```
fit <- model$estimate(data=X)

*** caught illegal operation ***
address 0x7fffa39b0e97, cause 'illegal opcode'

Trackback:
  1: dyn.load(x = m$libfile)
  2: CallFunction("ctsmdriver", .self, rho, verbose = verbose)
  3: model$estimate(data = X)
```

So, I am wondering if the package is not installed correctly or if their is a bug in the package (maybe because of the double slashes in the path in the error message).

If I manually go look for the shared object, `model5a613c359b3f.so`, it actually exist on my computer.

Regarding the gfortran compiler I get the following form the therminal:

```
~ $ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (GCC) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

~ $ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

I would appreciate if someone could tell me if it is a installation error or a bug in the package. And secondly, come up with possible solutions.